# What does Cobol file status 9Â mean?

Tags: cobol, microfocus, cobol85, cobol.net, procobol

My issue is when I try to open on input a huge file (6GB) ,
there's a message that says:

```
cobol file status code 9Â
```

I compiled the program and it has no errors, but when I try to run it,
I use a small one (3 GB for example) my program work correctly.

Any ideas ?

Variable declaration:

```
SELECT                                                       
MYFILE ASSIGN     MYFILE
ACCESS SEQUENTIAL 
STATUS IS XZ-STATUS6.  
===
OPEN INPUT  MYFILE 
===
READ  MYFILE NEXT AT  END  MOVE  1  TO  ZFIN-F3
```

Comment: Do you run on 32 or 64 bit? There may be a limit related to that...

Comment: Likely, 194 - File size too large

Comment: Which COBOL? You have used every COBOL tag you could find. You should use the one specific to the version that you use. I have no idea as to which manual I should be referring.

Comment: In ISO-8859-1 Â is 194 - so definitely "File size too large".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [this link](https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/nx30books/fhfsta.htm), which includes some info which may apply in your case. Some of the info included there:

1. About File Status

> If you have a file status data-item defined for a file, then after every input/output operation on the file (OPEN, CLOSE, READ, WRITE, REWRITE, START and DELETE) the run-time system updates it to indicate how the operation completed.

> Defining a file status data-item is optional. If a file status data-item is not declared and a serious file error occurs, the COBOL run-time system displays an error message and aborts your program.

> You should check the file status data-item after each input/output operation, to see if the operation completed successfully.

2. About a file status data-item

> File status is a two-byte code. If the first byte of the file status data-item contains value 9, it indicates a COBOL run-time system error. In that case, the second byte is a binary field containing an error code.

3. Example code (ws-file-status corresponds to your XZ-STATUS6)

   ```
    ...
    working-storage section.
    01 ws-file-status.
       05 status-key-1                          pic x.
       05 status-key-2                          pic x.
       05 binary-status redefines status-key-2  pic 99 comp-x.
    ...
    ...
    procedure division.
    ...
    perform check-status.
    ...
    check-status.
       evaluate status-key-1
          when "0" next sentence
          when "1" display "end of file reached"
          ...
          when "9" display "run-time-system error"
             perform check-mf-error-message
       end-evaluate.
    ...
    check-mf-error-message.
       evaluate binary-status
          when 002 display "file not open"
          when 007 display "disk space exhausted"
          when 013 display "file not found"
          when 024 display "disk error    "
          when 065 display "file locked      "
          when 068 display "record locked    "
          when 039 display "record inconsistent"
          when 146 display "no current record  "
          when 180 display "file malformed     "
          when 208 display "network error      "
          when 213 display "too many locks     "
          when other display "not error status "
          display binary-status
       end-evaluate.
   ```

Note sure if your (bizarre) value `Â` will correspond with any of the listed values for `binary-status` (within `check-mf-error-message`), but at least it should help find out how to correctly display your actual file status code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your valuable feedbacks, the problem was in the size of an array that I use to calculate some large numbers, I have set my array to the max and it's worked fine now